# compare treeset for equality

Tags: java, collections, treeset

I have two sets of `HashSet` that i converted to `TreeSet` to sort it for ease of comparison. After converting `HashSet` to `TreeSet`. When i compare these two TreeSet using 'equals' function, it says they are different. I debug it, but it shows same content with same order. i can not understand what is wrong ?

```
   public class TestProductBundle {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // HashSet
        Set<ClassA> hashSetA = new HashSet<ClassA>() {
            {
                add(new ClassA("name", 1, "desc"));
                add(new ClassA("name", 2, "desc"));
                add(new ClassA("name", 3, "desc"));
            }
        };

        Set<ClassA> hashSetB = new HashSet<ClassA>() {
            {
                add(new ClassA("name", 1, "desc"));
                add(new ClassA("name", 2, "desc"));
                add(new ClassA("name", 3, "desc"));
            }
        };

        TreeSet<ClassA> treeSetA = new TreeSet<ClassA>(new CompareID()) {
            {
                addAll(hashSetA);
            }
        };

        TreeSet<ClassA> treeSetB = new TreeSet<ClassA>(new CompareID()) {
            {
                addAll(hashSetB);
            }
        };

        if (treeSetA.equals(treeSetB))
            System.out.println("Equal set of tree");
        else
            System.out.println("Unequal set of tree");   // this is result.
    }}
```

ClassA gives below:

```
class ClassA {
String name;
int id;
String desc;

public ClassA(String name, int id, String desc) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.desc = desc;
}

    int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

class CompareID implements Comparator<ClassA> {
    @Override
    public int compare(ClassA o1, ClassA o2) {
        if (o1.getId() > o2.getId())
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

Edit:
I tried `if (treeSetA.containsAll(treeSetB) && treeSetB.containsAll(treeSetA)` this condition also. But same result, `"Unequal set of tree"`

Comment: Well, your comperator never returns equality as you allways return `1` and `-1`.

Comment: `I have two sets of HashSet that i converted to TreeSet to sort it for ease of comparison` - that makes little sense. If you used HashSet correctly (i.e. overriding equals and hashCode), you could compare the two HashSets directly. The order doesn't matter when comparing two Sets.

Comment: @Eran `HashSet` is just a prototype because, the set of objects i get is more generic or 'compare' functionality should be independent of implementation of any type from `set`. If you know better way than converting into `TreeSet'. i welcome it.

Comment: @user3042916 TreeSet is also a specific implementation of Set. If the goal is just to find if two Sets are equal (i.e. containing the same elements, regardless of the order, since generic Set has no order), using HashSet directly would be more efficient than TreeSet (since lookup in HashSet requires constant time). You just have to override `equals` and `hashCode` in your `ClassA` class, and then you can use `equals` to compare the two HashSets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `compare` method allways returns unequality.

from the doc:

> [...]
>
> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.
>
> [..]

```
public int compare(ClassA o1, ClassA o2) {
    if (o1.getId() > o2.getId())
        return 1;
    else if(o2.getId() > o1.getId())
        return -1;
    // 0  indicates equality.
    else return 0;
}
```

Including this results in the output

```
Equal set of tree
```

Answer (score 1):

The real lesson here is: **study** the interfaces you are implementing. Don't just put down some code that makes the compiler happy.

You have to **understand** what it means when you @Override the compare function. So, you study the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for that. And that clearly tells you that compare should return <0 , 0, >0.

One of those three values. And not just **two** of them.

Comment: Thanks for advice! I follow it.

Answer (score 0):

From Java Comparator documentation:

> The ordering imposed by a comparator c on a set of elements S is said to be consistent with equals if and only if c.compare(e1, e2)==0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 in S.
>
> Caution should be exercised when using a comparator capable of
>   imposing an ordering inconsistent with equals to order a sorted set
>   (or sorted map). Suppose a sorted set (or sorted map) with an explicit
>   comparator c is used with elements (or keys) drawn from a set S. If
>   the ordering imposed by c on S is inconsistent with equals, the sorted
>   set (or sorted map) will behave "strangely." In particular the sorted
>   set (or sorted map) will violate the general contract for set (or
>   map), which is defined in terms of equals.

Your comparator never caters for equal objects. Also, ClassA does not override `equals`.